# The links to .xls files will not work on my intranet site?

Tags: html, excel, asp-classic

I am currently building an asp intranet site.

There are various helpful links that I need to include and some of them happen to be .xls files that are located on a local network within the company.

I link these documents just like I would any word docs (which work fine by the way).

```
<a href="file:///P:/-Projects-/SCHEDULE.xls" target="_blank"><span>Schedule</span></a>
```

The link above works if I simply copy and paste the raw address into my browser (a pop-up window comes up asking me to open the file in Excel). But when I make this a link on the intranet site and try to click on it, nothing happens. I can see the link when I hover over it on the status bar but that's it. It is non-clickable. Anyone have any idea what is causing this and how to fix it?

I should mention that two of these .xls files are password-protected but one of them is simply a read-only file which can be opened by anyone.

I am 100% sure this has nothing to do with css styling because the same thing happens in the current (old) intranet site made by someone else and I use these links on different menu bars as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use wrong syntax for shared files, try this:

`file:///P:\-Projects-\SCHEDULE.xls`

Backslashes are still valid for the path part. Moreover, I'm not sure whether Sharepoint may recognize correctly path to most likely network drive `P:`.

For me such link to local share works:

`file:///\\fs-1\Install\Windows\Servers\DB\MSSQL\SQL2005\en_sql_server_2005_service_pack_4_x64.exe`

Comment: I tried changing it to what you suggested but the problem still occurs. Curiously, the status bar still displays it as "file:///P:/-Projects-/SCHEDULE.xls" when I hover over the anchor but when I inspect the element, the slash changes have definitely been applied.

Comment: `file://///fs-1/Install/Windows/Servers/DB/MSSQL/SQL2005/` - this is how Firefox shows opened link in address bar. I'd rather look towards `P:` suggestion.

Comment: I just found this article: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don%27t_work However, it says IE should be able to open local files (and suggests an IE tab add-on), but the links don't work in IE8 for me either.

Comment: @user1781568 I have no more suggestions, sorry. perhaps others will bring something new.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to add the site to the "Trusted Sites" list.

Opening intranet files without the user knowing is considered a secruity threat.

In IE go to Internet Options ->  Security -> Trusted Sites then add the site.

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/after-latest-update-ie-wont-open-network-file/172e4ac3-1c1f-4948-8a3f-c8c344eae06d